# Infinity PagerAdapter issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I designed infinity adapter for my `PagerAdapter`, also I extended `ViewPager` class and made my own custom `ViewPager` for implementing slideshow mechanism.

There is two problem:

1- When I implement infinity view I lost smooth scrolling on `setCurrent(page, smooth scroll)`, It's not work!!!

2- `ViewPager` `setPageMargin()` method has different result on different display density.

Any suggestion would be appreciated...

Comment: for #2, is it possible you didn't convert from dp to pixels? usually, when setting the units in code, it will use pixels units instead of dp.

Comment: for #1, have you checked this solution: https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

Comment: @androiddeveloper Thanks mate #1 has been solved by myself, About #2 I set the value in `dimens.xml`, should I convert it to `px`?

Comment: about #2, if you use dp there, then it should be fine, but in the code, use getResources().getDimension(...).

Comment: @androiddeveloper tried with `getDimension()` but it's still different.